# Default access modifier of constructor in Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, access-modifiers, default-constructor

I did a little web search and came to know that default constructor's access modifier is same as the access level of class, but take a look.

Here is one class

```
package package2;
public class TestClass1 {
    TestClass1()
    {
        System.out.println("In parent's contructor");
    }
}
```

and here is another which inherits from the previous one

```
package package2;

public class TestClass2 extends TestClass1 {

      TestClass2()
     {
         System.out.println("In TestClass2's contructor");
     }

}
```

But when i try to create the object of `TestClass2`

```
import package2.*;

class MainClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TestClass2 t2 = new TestClass2(); //Says the constructor TestClass2() is not visible.

    }
 }
```

I don't understand, both classes `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` have public access so their constructors must also be implicitly public. Which concept  am I missing here ? o.O

Comment: Where did you read the default access specifier of constructor is the same as that of it's class?

Comment: `Default constructor != Default access specifier of constructor`. The JLS talks about the implicit constructor (The one which gets created automatically if you don't define any in your class).

Comment: @Salim - You'd like to upvote the answer too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did a little web search and came to know that default constructor's
>   access specifier is same as the access level of class

There is a difference between default constructor and the one which you've declared. The default constructor is the one which you don't declare inside the class.

*The current one in your code is not a default constructor*. And, it has default(package-private --- no explicit modifier) acccess as you've omitted any access modifier from it.

> Which concept am I missing here ?

So, your class from other package is not able to find it, because of the limitation of default access.

Comment: `default` is a keyword in switch statements, not an access modifier, and there is no such thing as an access specifier in Java.

Comment: @EJP - Sorry, this confusion between access-specifier and access-modifer is taking me down! Thanks for editing. And, from default,, I referred to package-private.

Answer (score 1):

Oh they are public, but to the package only (we call it the default-access-modifier)!

The access-modifiers make no difference between constructors and methods and fields.

Move MainClass to the same package like this:

```
package package2; // <-- !
import package2.*;

class MainClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TestClass2 t2 = new TestClass2(); //OK!
    }
}
```

Or make the Constructors real public

```
public TestClass2()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicit constructor is the constructor when you do not write any constructor. In your code you have explicitly written the constructor, so they are not implicit.
Implicit constructor is provided by Java internally and it is not visible. For Example:

```
package package2;
public class TestClass1 {
}
```

In the above class we have not written any constructor.

```
package main;
class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            TestClass1 t2 = new TestClass1(); //Although we have not written any constructor for TestClass1, but we are able to create object for it. This object creation is done by calling TestClass1's costructor, which is an implicit, invisible constructor provided by java when we explicitly do not write any constructor. 
        }
}
```

Above, although we have not written any constructor for TestClass1, but we are able to create object for it. This object creation is done by calling TestClass1's costructor, which is an implicit, invisible constructor provided by java when we explicitly do not write any constructor.

In your example, you have explicitly written the constructor and made it default(default means not making public or private), which means it will only be accessible in the same package. If you try to call this constructor from any class which is outside the package, you'll get the error that the constructor is not visible as in your case:

```
import package2.*;

    class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            TestClass2 t2 = new TestClass2(); //Says the constructor TestClass2() is not visible.
        }
     }
```